# Invalid data: Missing delimiter ":" [0x3a] nodejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, binary

I'm getting this error:

> Error: Invalid data: Missing delimiter ":" [0x3a]
>       at Function.decode.find (/Users/Seleena/Documents/torrent/node_modules/bencode/lib/decode.js:114:9)
>       at Function.decode.buffer (/Users/Seleena/Documents/torrent/node_modules/bencode/lib/decode.js:159:20)
>       at Function.decode.dictionary (/Users/Seleena/Documents/torrent/node_modules/bencode/lib/decode.js:127:17)
>       at Function.decode.next (../Documents/torrent/node_modules/bencode/lib/decode.js:94:21)
>       at Function.decode.dictionary (../Documents/torrent/node_modules/bencode/lib/decode.js:127:36)
>       at Function.decode.next (../Documents/torrent/node_modules/bencode/lib/decode.js:94:21)
>       at Object.decode (../Documents/torrent/node_modules/bencode/lib/decode.js:83:17)
>       at Object. (/Users/Seleena/Documents/torrent/index.js:5:25)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)

by running this code

```
const fs = require('fs');
const bencode = require('bencode');
const torrent = bencode.decode(fs.readFileSync('puppy.torrent'));
console.log(torrent.announce.toString('utf8'));
```

This is my puppy.torrent file

```
d8:announce43:udp://tracker.coppersurfer.tk:6969/announce10:created by13:uTorrent/187013:creation datei1462355939e8:encoding5:UTF-84:infod6:lengthi124234e4:name9:puppy.jpg12:piece lengthi16384e6:pieces160:T�k�/�_(�S\u0011h%���+]q\'B\u0018�٠:����p"�j����1-g"\u0018�s(\u001b\u000f���V��=�h�m\u0017a�nF�2���N\r�ǩ�_�\u001e"2���\'�wO���-;\u0004ע\u0017�ؑ��L&����0\u001f�D_9��\t\\��O�h,n\u001a5g�(��仑,�\\߰�%��U��\u0019��C\u0007>��df��ee
```

Can anyone explain to me why I'm getting this error message and how to fix it?

Comment: Post the whole error please

Comment: I have post now the whole error

Comment: Looks like the format of the torrent string you're passing in is either incorrect or not supported by your decoder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tracker I used was the problem. After creating a new torrent file with a different tracker, I got the right output.